# webflow.xsd - Start state is missing. Add at least one state to the flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-3, spring-webflow-2, spring-4

I am working with Spring Core 4.0.7 and Spring Web Flow 2.4.0

Using `Spring Tool Suite` I am able to create a `Spring Web Flow Definition File`

For the `<flow>` tag it generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
```

Observe `spring-webflow-2.0.xsd`

When I try to use the `validation-hints` attribute how the following:

```
<view-state id="registrar" 
            view="deportista.flow.formulario.registro"
            model="deportista"
            validation-hints="'….someValue'" >
```

The editor put an underline red. So the attribute is wrong or is not valid.

I did realize that If I change:

from

- `spring-webflow-2.0.xsd`

to

- `spring-webflow.xsd` (-2.0 has been removed)

It is recognized and goes well until I *build* the application..
In the left part of the `<flow>` tag appears a red circle with a x. 
If I see the message it says:

> Start state is missing. Add at least one state to the flow

Funny because I have in the beginning

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="deportistaAction.createDeportista()" 
              result-type="com.manuel.jordan.domain.Deportista" 
              result="flowScope.deportista"/>
</on-start>

<view-state id="registrar" 
            view="deportista.flow.formulario.registro"
            model="deportista"
            validation-hints="'…someValue'" 
            >
```

Even with that error, the flow process works fine. I mean, the error appears only in the `<flow>` definition but when the flow is executed all work fine, practically how if the error never has been generated.

What is wrong? I did a research through Google, and it has been reported how a kind of old bug time ago and it has been already fixed. So wondered why this situation appears again.